# ¿Cómo conseguir el id del usuario que está actualmente logueado en un b-button en vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, id

Necesito saber el id del usuario que está actualmente logueado, para poder editar sus datos personales (perfil). Actualmente estoy probando con lo siguiente --> params: {usuarioId: this.$session.get('user_id')}
También he pensado en utilizar this.credentials

Dejo el código completo:

```
<template>
  <div class="LandingUsuario">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <div class="">
    <b-button size="sm" :to="{name: 'PronosticadorUsuario'}" variant="primary">
            Pronosticador
    </b-button>
    <b-button size="sm" :to="{name: 'Resultados'}" variant="primary">
            Resultados ReGOLsivo
    </b-button>
    <b-button size="sm" :to="{name: 'Clasificacion'}" variant="primary">
            Clasificación
    </b-button>
    <b-button size="sm" :to="{name: 'PerfilUsuario', params: {usuarioId: this.$session.get('user_id')}}" variant="primary">
            Perfil
    </b-button>
    <b-button size="sm" :to="{name: 'Logros'}" variant="primary">
            Logros
    </b-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Francisco, faltan elementos importantes en tu pregunta. 
- Cómo estas autenticando a tu usuario? 
- Estas pensando en dar compatibilidad a navegadores legados?

En general lo que guardas es el token de autenticación, con el que vas a consultar a tu API y así asegurar que la información obtenida sea la del usuario autenticado. Por tanto, todas las vistas que generaste deberían tener una lógica para rescatar este token y enviarlo a tu API para obtener y enviar información consistente con el usuario "logueado"

Comment: Estoy usando autenticación mediante token, concretamente el JWT. Respecto a la compatibilidad, basta con que funcione en Google Chrome, de momento estoy trabajando solo en local, posteriormente cuando termine de desarrollar la aplicación, la desplegaré. Lo más probable es que esa expresión que he puesto del this.$session no esté bien expresada. Tengo otra pregunta, ¿puedo obtener el id del usuario mediante su token?

Comment: Si estas usando JWT, la información del usuario está contenida en la cadena. Salvo que la API te pida enviar explicitamente el id del usuario, no deberías enviarla ya que el token es suficiente para validar quien es el usuario logueado.

Comment: Entonces ¿que podría hacer para cuando acceda a editar la información del perfil, me aparezcan los campos ya rellenados con el valor que tienen actualmente?. Mi idea era hacerlo con el id del usuario, pero si con el token se puede, ¿cómo sería?

Comment: Tu tienes el control de la API? Es decir, tu la estas desarrollando? El token debe proveer la información necesaria para identificar al usuario en el payload. Si la API la estas desarrollando tu, modifica la API para que se envíe por esa via. De lo contrario, puedes averiguar si vienen esta información decodificando el payload del cuerdo del token y si no viene, consultar con quien te provee la API, de que manera rescatas el id del usuario.

Comment: Si, estoy utilizando Django, tengo mis modelos creados y demás.